# Why does glDispatchCompute fail after calling glClear?

Tags: opengl, graphics, glsl, shader

I'm trying to use a compute shader in OpenGL after I called glClear but the call to glDispatchCompute always gives me "GL_INVALID_OPERATION error generated. State(s) are invalid: program pipeline config."
The gpu is a NVidia Quadro K5100M with driver version 376.54.
I created a small test program that only loads a compute shader, clears and calls dispatch.
My render loop looks like this:

```
glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
glUseProgramStages(ProgramPipeline, GL_COMPUTE_SHADER_BIT, ComputeShader);
glDispatchCompute(1, 1, 1);
glUseProgramStages(ProgramPipeline, GL_ALL_SHADER_BITS, 0);
```

The error only occurs when glUseProgramStages is called directly after glClear. When I leave out the clear or just switch it with glUseProgramStages there is no error anymore. When I remove the shader reset at the end I only get an error in the first iteration but after that it works.
The shader and the pipeline itself are created like that:

```
glGenProgramPipelines(1, &ProgramPipeline);
glBindProgramPipeline(ProgramPipeline);

GLuint ShaderID = glCreateShader(GL_COMPUTE_SHADER);
GLint Result;
GLint InfoLogLength;

glShaderSource(ShaderID, 1, &pShader, NULL);
glCompileShader(ShaderID);

glGetShaderiv(ShaderID, GL_COMPILE_STATUS, &Result);
glGetShaderiv(ShaderID, GL_INFO_LOG_LENGTH, &InfoLogLength);
if (InfoLogLength > 0) {
    std::vector<char> Error(InfoLogLength + 1);
    glGetShaderInfoLog(ShaderID, InfoLogLength, NULL, &Error[0]);
    std::cout << Error.data() << '\n';
}

GLuint ProgramID = glCreateProgram();
glProgramParameteri(ProgramID, GL_PROGRAM_SEPARABLE, GL_TRUE);
glAttachShader(ProgramID, ShaderID);
glLinkProgram(ProgramID);

glGetProgramiv(ProgramID, GL_LINK_STATUS, &Result);
glGetProgramiv(ProgramID, GL_INFO_LOG_LENGTH, &InfoLogLength);
if (InfoLogLength > 0) {
    std::vector<char> Error(InfoLogLength + 1);
    glGetProgramInfoLog(ProgramID, InfoLogLength, NULL, &Error[0]);
    std::cout << &Error[0] << '\n';
}

ComputeShader = ProgramID;
```

Comment: I have the same problem with an NVidia Geforce GTX 1080 and driver version 378.92. But I have no solution for this issue.

Comment: `glUseProgramStages` Please stop using this function as though it were `glUseProgram`. That's clearly the function you want, so just use that one. You should never constantly be binding and unbinding programs from a pipeline, which is what `glUseProgramStages` does.

Comment: What is the end goal here? Saying something doesn't work, doesn't explain what you want working.